# KERBEROS - restricting users from logging into specific hosts in realm

Tags: kerberos, kdc

I have configured kerberos on linux machine to serve as a single point for user authorisation management. now I want to restrict few users from logging into specific linux hosts. for example.

I have user admin, developer and tester. and I have 3 linux client machine which are running with centos7., machine1, machine2 and machine3.

user admin can login to both 3 client machine.
user developer can login to client machine1 and machine2.
user tester can only login to client machine3.

need guidance to configure the above policy.

Comment: Any details about these hypothetical "machines": Windows? Linux? AIX? IBM mainframe? lawnmower?

Comment: these are linux machines with centos7

Comment: Kerberos is about _authentication_, not _authorization_. You need LDAP groups and SSSD configuration > "what groups do that (authenticated) user belong to? does any of these groups grant access to this Linux box?"

Comment: I tried to explore the LDAP groups feature but did not able to got clear insight of it.

but for my requirement with LDAP I configured the sshd_config of a servers with the directive "AllowUsers user1 user2". which suffice my requirement.